# Bluetooth LE - PAN1720 BlueRadios Serial Port Profile with Windows

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a Single-Mode Bluetooth Low Energy PAN1720BR BLE dongle which is loaded with the firmware "BlueRadios nBlue 1.2.1.3.1.0-PAN1720" (latest). When plugged to a computer, I can control and configure this PAN1720BR module with AT Commands through a terminal application on the computer.

With a second computer equipped with a standard BLE dongle, I can pair and connect to the PAN1720BR. See configuration below:

PC1 + PAN1720BR <---- BT 4.0 ----> PC2 + Standard BLE dongle + App running on PC2

The problem is that BLE does not have an SPP profile, so to establish a communication between the two PCs, I need to write an application on PC2. The PAN1720BR has a proprietary profile called BlueRadios Serial Port (BRPS) which is not a standard.

BlueRadios provides libraries for iOS and Android so that we can connect a cellphone to a PAN1720BR and communicate wih it. But they are silent about how to connect a PC (Windows) to a PAN1720BR. When establishing the connection, the Battery service (standard) installs properly on PC2, but the service corresponding to BRSP does not install, driver is missing. What is going on here is not very clear to me.

My goal is to write an application to be run on PC2 to enable communication between the two PCs. My question is, how can I access the Bluetooth with my application? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe my app needs to access the ATT/GATT layer in order to read/write data.

Do you have any sample code that would help, in Java (prefered), C/C++, C# or anything else that would help on Windows?

Thank you

Comment: Which is the library you mention in your question?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar problem, were you able to solve it or get some sample code (preferably in C#)?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I was not able to solve the issue in this configuration. If I remember well, I ended up writting my own custom BLE profile, and an app on Windows 8.1 in C#/VB.NET (Windows 7 and earlier do not enable BLE access). Sorry but I cannot give any more information as I don't remember well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an App with BLE Module from BlueRadios you must use the ATT/GATT Profile or you use the library from BlueRadios with there BRSP Profile.

Comment: How can a developer obtain this BlueRadios library ? it can be purchased?